# Running Access Form from Excel VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am using Excel 2013 and Access 2013. My access query has a form that takes2 inputs, "start date" and "end date", and then runs a macro in access. Is there a way I can use VBA to input "start date" and "end date" from excel and run the form in access? Here is what I have tried, but I get an error saying "The action or method is invalid because the form or report isn't bound to a table or query"

```
Sub RunAccessQuery()

Dim strDatabasePath As String
Dim appAccess As Access.Application
Dim startDate As Date
Dim endDate As Date

startDate = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("B2").Value

strDatabasePath = "access database path"
Set appAccess = New Access.Application
With appAccess
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    .OpenCurrentDatabase strDatabasePath
    .DoCmd.OpenForm "inputForm", , , "start =" & startDate
    '.Quit
End With
Set appAccess = Nothing

ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
MsgBox ("Data has been updated")

End Sub
```

This is what my form looks like. Click me runs a macro, the first text box holds variable "start" and second one holds variable "end"

[image]

Comment: Please provide data on the form (record source, which controls are on it, etc).

Comment: theres 2 text boxes that you fill with a start date and end date (first text box holds variable "start" and second holds variable "end". then theres a button at the button that will run a macro when clicked. what is record source?

Comment: I do not get that error. DB opens, form opens, DB closes. I even confirmed with `.Visible = True`. However, the form is not filtered to the desired record until I change code to: `"start = #" & startDate & "#"`. What is the form's RecordSource - a table, query, SQL statement?

Comment: the form just runs a macro. i dont think its attached to a query or table

Comment: Then why would you use the OpenForm WHERE CONDITION argument? Remove that from your code.

Comment: I am trying to pass the start and end date from excel into the two variables "start" and "end" in access

Comment: Either use OpenArgs argument or see Erik's answer to directly set value of textbox. I have executed a button Click event from VBA in Access, example: `Call btnExecute_Click`. However, not having success calling remotely from Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I assume your form has no recordsource, and the controls are unbound, the following should avoid the error you've encountered:

```
Sub RunAccessQuery()

Dim strDatabasePath As String
Dim appAccess As Access.Application
Dim startDate As Date
Dim endDate As Date

startDate = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("B2").Value

strDatabasePath = "access database path"
Set appAccess = New Access.Application
With appAccess
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    .OpenCurrentDatabase strDatabasePath
    .DoCmd.OpenForm "inputForm"
    .Forms("inputForm").start = startDate
    '.Quit
End With
Set appAccess = Nothing

ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
MsgBox ("Data has been updated")

End Sub
```

However, this still does nothing more than just open the form and set the start date, and closes Access immediately after.

Comment: " .Forms("inputForm").start = startDate " Thats what i was looking for. I just put a .DoCmd.RunMacro "macro" afterward to run the macro that the form should run. I just didnt know how to set the variables in the form. Thank you!